# regex, get the first characters after the line when you find a keyword

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Ive been mashing with regex builders and tutorials and cant figure this out. I have a keyword which i can find and i need to find the timestamp on either that same line or the next line.

my text looks something like this

```
16:51:35.536 This is a bunch of completely random text although it has a keyword. This keyword is unique
16:51:35.806 This is another line which has all sorts of crap i dont really care about.
```

Now what im trying to capture is either the first 8 characters to get the timestamp ie 16:51:35

so im trying to do something like this

```
it has a keyword (.*) ([0-9){2}:[0-9){2}:[0-9){2})
```

but for whatever reason it gets stuck on that line even if i add /m at the end or /s or /S

This works on getting to the next line:

```
([\s\S]*)
```

so i tried

```
it has a keyword ([\s\S]*)(?=[0-9){2}:[0-9){2}:[0-9){2}) but that didnt work either
```

Im pretty sure its less complicated than im making it, any ideas

Comment: For starters, did you really mean `[0-9)` rather than `[0-9]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first eight characters of a line with the keyword string 'foobar', then you can use:

```
^(.{8})[^\n]*foobar.*?$
```

You can see this work at http://rubular.com/r/gW8GCRrYkg  This is easily modified to get the first eight characters of the next line instead or to put constraints on the first eight characters.